# Как сохранить расположение панелей, размер и положение окна ВМ Genymotion?

Tags: android, genymotion

Как сохранить размеры и положение окна виртуальной машины Genymotion, а так же расположение панелей Widgets и Device? Постоянно сбрасывается в дефолт при выключении ВМ.
Попутно - возможно ли запускать конкретную ВМ без запуска самого Genymotion (окна, которое показывает мои виртуальные машины)